# Compilng Error With modern OpenGL and GLEW Libraray

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I am trying to use glew but I keep getting an error when compiling. I'm running Ubuntu and have a Nvidia graphics card. I've installed glew using apt. I get the error when compiling with:

```
g++ -c main.cpp && g++ main.o -o main -lGL -lGLU -lglfw -lglut
```

This is my code :

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fputs(description, stderr);
}
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(1336, 768, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);


    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex2f(-0.5f,-0.5f);
        glVertex2f( 0.0f, 0.5f);
        glVertex2f( 0.5f,-0.5f);
        glEnd();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And This is my Error Message

```
´´´
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:85:2: error: #error gl.h included before glew.h
   85 | #error gl.h included before glew.h
      |  ^~~~~
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:97:2: error: #error glext.h included before glew.h
   97 | #error glext.h included before glew.h
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:15756:28: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef void (* PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELFVSGIXPROC)(GLenum, GLfloat*)’
15756 | typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELFVSGIXPROC) (GLenum pname, GLfloat* params);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2050,
                 from /usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h:210,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:12301:25: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef void (* PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELFVSGIXPROC)(GLenum, const GLfloat*)’
12301 | typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELFVSGIXPROC) (GLenum pname, const GLfloat *params);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:15758:28: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef void (* PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELIVSGIXPROC)(GLenum, GLint*)’
15758 | typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELIVSGIXPROC) (GLenum pname, GLint* params);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2050,
                 from /usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h:210,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:12303:25: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef void (* PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELIVSGIXPROC)(GLenum, const GLint*)’
12303 | typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELIVSGIXPROC) (GLenum pname, const GLint *params);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:15760:28: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef void (* PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTFVSGIXPROC)(GLenum, GLenum, GLfloat*)’
15760 | typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTFVSGIXPROC) (GLenum light, GLenum pname, GLfloat* params);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2050,
                 from /usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h:210,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:12297:25: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef void (* PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTFVSGIXPROC)(GLenum, GLenum, const GLfloat*)’
12297 | typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTFVSGIXPROC) (GLenum light, GLenum pname, const GLfloat *params);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:15762:28: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef void (* PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTIVSGIXPROC)(GLenum, GLenum, GLint*)’
15762 | typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTIVSGIXPROC) (GLenum light, GLenum pname, GLint* params);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2050,
                 from /usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h:210,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:12299:25: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef void (* PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTIVSGIXPROC)(GLenum, GLenum, const GLint*)’
12299 | typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTIVSGIXPROC) (GLenum light, GLenum pname, const GLint *params);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:15769:28: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef void (* PFNGLGETFRAGMENTMATERIALFVSGIXPROC)(GLenum, GLenum, const GLfloat*)’
15769 | typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLGETFRAGMENTMATERIALFVSGIXPROC) (GLenum face, GLenum pname, const GLfloat* data);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2050,
                 from /usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h:210,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:12310:25: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef void (* PFNGLGETFRAGMENTMATERIALFVSGIXPROC)(GLenum, GLenum, GLfloat*)’
12310 | typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLGETFRAGMENTMATERIALFVSGIXPROC) (GLenum face, GLenum pname, GLfloat *params);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:15770:28: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef void (* PFNGLGETFRAGMENTMATERIALIVSGIXPROC)(GLenum, GLenum, const GLint*)’
15770 | typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLGETFRAGMENTMATERIALIVSGIXPROC) (GLenum face, GLenum pname, const GLint* data);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2050,
                 from /usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h:210,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:12311:25: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef void (* PFNGLGETFRAGMENTMATERIALIVSGIXPROC)(GLenum, GLenum, GLint*)’
12311 | typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLGETFRAGMENTMATERIALIVSGIXPROC) (GLenum face, GLenum pname, GLint *params);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16433:17: error: ‘PFNGLCLIENTACTIVETEXTUREPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLCLIENTACTIVETEXTUREARBPROC’?
16433 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCLIENTACTIVETEXTUREPROC __glewClientActiveTexture;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLCLIENTACTIVETEXTUREARBPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16441:17: error: ‘PFNGLLOADTRANSPOSEMATRIXDPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLLOADTRANSPOSEMATRIXDARBPROC’?
16441 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLLOADTRANSPOSEMATRIXDPROC __glewLoadTransposeMatrixd;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLLOADTRANSPOSEMATRIXDARBPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16442:17: error: ‘PFNGLLOADTRANSPOSEMATRIXFPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLLOADTRANSPOSEMATRIXFARBPROC’?
16442 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLLOADTRANSPOSEMATRIXFPROC __glewLoadTransposeMatrixf;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLLOADTRANSPOSEMATRIXFARBPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16443:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTTRANSPOSEMATRIXDPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTTRANSPOSEMATRIXDARBPROC’?
16443 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTTRANSPOSEMATRIXDPROC __glewMultTransposeMatrixd;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTTRANSPOSEMATRIXDARBPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16444:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTTRANSPOSEMATRIXFPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTTRANSPOSEMATRIXFARBPROC’?
16444 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTTRANSPOSEMATRIXFPROC __glewMultTransposeMatrixf;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTTRANSPOSEMATRIXFARBPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16445:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1DPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC’?
16445 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1DPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1d;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16446:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1DVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1HNVPROC’?
16446 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1DVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1dv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1HNVPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16447:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1FPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC’?
16447 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1FPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1f;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16448:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1FVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1HNVPROC’?
16448 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1FVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1fv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1HNVPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16449:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1IPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC’?
16449 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1IPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1i;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16450:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1IVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1HNVPROC’?
16450 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1IVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1iv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1HNVPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16451:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1SPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC’?
16451 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1SPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1s;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16452:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1SVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1HNVPROC’?
16452 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1SVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1sv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1HNVPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16453:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2DPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC’?
16453 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2DPROC __glewMultiTexCoord2d;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16454:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2DVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2HNVPROC’?
16454 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2DVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord2dv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2HNVPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16455:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2FPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC’?
16455 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2FPROC __glewMultiTexCoord2f;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16456:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2FVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2HNVPROC’?
16456 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2FVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord2fv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2HNVPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16457:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2IPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC’?
16457 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2IPROC __glewMultiTexCoord2i;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16458:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2IVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2HNVPROC’?
16458 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2IVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord2iv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2HNVPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16459:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2SPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC’?
16459 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2SPROC __glewMultiTexCoord2s;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16460:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2SVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2HNVPROC’?
16460 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2SVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord2sv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2HNVPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16461:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3DPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC’?
16461 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3DPROC __glewMultiTexCoord3d;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16462:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3DVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3HNVPROC’?
16462 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3DVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord3dv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3HNVPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16463:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3FPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC’?
16463 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3FPROC __glewMultiTexCoord3f;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16464:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3FVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3HNVPROC’?
16464 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3FVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord3fv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3HNVPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16465:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3IPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC’?
16465 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3IPROC __glewMultiTexCoord3i;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16466:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3IVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3HNVPROC’?
16466 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3IVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord3iv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3HNVPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16467:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3SPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC’?
16467 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3SPROC __glewMultiTexCoord3s;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16468:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3SVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3HNVPROC’?
16468 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3SVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord3sv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD3HNVPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16469:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4DPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC’?
16469 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4DPROC __glewMultiTexCoord4d;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16470:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4DVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC’?
16470 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4DVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord4dv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16471:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4FPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC’?
16471 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4FPROC __glewMultiTexCoord4f;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16472:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4FVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC’?
16472 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4FVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord4fv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16473:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4IPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC’?
16473 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4IPROC __glewMultiTexCoord4i;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16474:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4IVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC’?
16474 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4IVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord4iv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16475:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4SPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC’?
16475 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4SPROC __glewMultiTexCoord4s;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16476:17: error: ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4SVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC’?
16476 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4SVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord4sv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17107:17: error: ‘PFNGLCOLORSUBTABLEPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLCOLORSUBTABLEEXTPROC’?
17107 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCOLORSUBTABLEPROC __glewColorSubTable;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLCOLORSUBTABLEEXTPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17108:17: error: ‘PFNGLCOLORTABLEPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLCOLORTABLESGIPROC’?
17108 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCOLORTABLEPROC __glewColorTable;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLCOLORTABLESGIPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17109:17: error: ‘PFNGLCOLORTABLEPARAMETERFVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLCOLORTABLEPARAMETERFVSGIPROC’?
17109 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCOLORTABLEPARAMETERFVPROC __glewColorTableParameterfv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLCOLORTABLEPARAMETERFVSGIPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17110:17: error: ‘PFNGLCOLORTABLEPARAMETERIVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLCOLORTABLEPARAMETERIVSGIPROC’?
17110 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCOLORTABLEPARAMETERIVPROC __glewColorTableParameteriv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLCOLORTABLEPARAMETERIVSGIPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17111:17: error: ‘PFNGLCONVOLUTIONFILTER1DPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLCONVOLUTIONFILTER1DEXTPROC’?
17111 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCONVOLUTIONFILTER1DPROC __glewConvolutionFilter1D;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLCONVOLUTIONFILTER1DEXTPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17112:17: error: ‘PFNGLCONVOLUTIONFILTER2DPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLCONVOLUTIONFILTER2DEXTPROC’?
17112 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCONVOLUTIONFILTER2DPROC __glewConvolutionFilter2D;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLCONVOLUTIONFILTER2DEXTPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17113:17: error: ‘PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERFPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERFEXTPROC’?
17113 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERFPROC __glewConvolutionParameterf;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERFEXTPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17114:17: error: ‘PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERFVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERFVEXTPROC’?
17114 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERFVPROC __glewConvolutionParameterfv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERFVEXTPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17115:17: error: ‘PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERIPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERIEXTPROC’?
17115 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERIPROC __glewConvolutionParameteri;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERIEXTPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17116:17: error: ‘PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERIVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERIVEXTPROC’?
17116 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERIVPROC __glewConvolutionParameteriv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERIVEXTPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17117:17: error: ‘PFNGLCOPYCOLORSUBTABLEPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLCOPYCOLORSUBTABLEEXTPROC’?
17117 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCOPYCOLORSUBTABLEPROC __glewCopyColorSubTable;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLCOPYCOLORSUBTABLEEXTPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17118:17: error: ‘PFNGLCOPYCOLORTABLEPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLCOPYCOLORTABLESGIPROC’?
17118 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCOPYCOLORTABLEPROC __glewCopyColorTable;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLCOPYCOLORTABLESGIPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17119:17: error: ‘PFNGLCOPYCONVOLUTIONFILTER1DPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLCOPYCONVOLUTIONFILTER1DEXTPROC’?
17119 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCOPYCONVOLUTIONFILTER1DPROC __glewCopyConvolutionFilter1D;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLCOPYCONVOLUTIONFILTER1DEXTPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17120:17: error: ‘PFNGLCOPYCONVOLUTIONFILTER2DPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLCOPYCONVOLUTIONFILTER2DEXTPROC’?
17120 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCOPYCONVOLUTIONFILTER2DPROC __glewCopyConvolutionFilter2D;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLCOPYCONVOLUTIONFILTER2DEXTPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17121:17: error: ‘PFNGLGETCOLORTABLEPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLGETNCOLORTABLEPROC’?
17121 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETCOLORTABLEPROC __glewGetColorTable;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLGETNCOLORTABLEPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17122:17: error: ‘PFNGLGETCOLORTABLEPARAMETERFVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLGETCOLORTABLEPARAMETERFVSGIPROC’?
17122 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETCOLORTABLEPARAMETERFVPROC __glewGetColorTableParameterfv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLGETCOLORTABLEPARAMETERFVSGIPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17123:17: error: ‘PFNGLGETCOLORTABLEPARAMETERIVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLGETCOLORTABLEPARAMETERIVSGIPROC’?
17123 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETCOLORTABLEPARAMETERIVPROC __glewGetColorTableParameteriv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLGETCOLORTABLEPARAMETERIVSGIPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17124:17: error: ‘PFNGLGETCONVOLUTIONFILTERPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLGETNCONVOLUTIONFILTERPROC’?
17124 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETCONVOLUTIONFILTERPROC __glewGetConvolutionFilter;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLGETNCONVOLUTIONFILTERPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17125:17: error: ‘PFNGLGETCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERFVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLGETCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERFVEXTPROC’?
17125 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERFVPROC __glewGetConvolutionParameterfv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLGETCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERFVEXTPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17126:17: error: ‘PFNGLGETCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERIVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLGETCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERIVEXTPROC’?
17126 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERIVPROC __glewGetConvolutionParameteriv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLGETCONVOLUTIONPARAMETERIVEXTPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17127:17: error: ‘PFNGLGETHISTOGRAMPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLGETNHISTOGRAMPROC’?
17127 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETHISTOGRAMPROC __glewGetHistogram;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLGETNHISTOGRAMPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17128:17: error: ‘PFNGLGETHISTOGRAMPARAMETERFVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLGETHISTOGRAMPARAMETERFVEXTPROC’?
17128 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETHISTOGRAMPARAMETERFVPROC __glewGetHistogramParameterfv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLGETHISTOGRAMPARAMETERFVEXTPROC
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:17129:17: error: ‘PFNGLGETHISTOGRAMPARAMETERIVPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLGETHISTOGRAMPARAMETERIVEXTPROC’?
17129 | GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETHISTOGRAMPARAMETERIVPROC __glewGetHistogramParameteriv;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 PFNGLGETHISTOGRAMPARAMETERIVEXTPROC

´´´
```

there are a few more errors like that but Stack overflow didnt allow me to post over 30000 characters.

Answer (score 2):

Reading your error message

> ```
> /usr/include/GL/glew.h:85:2: error: #error gl.h included before glew.h
> ```

yields very relevant information. `glew.h` must be included before (or in the best possible case, *instead of* the old `GL.h`), and `glfw3.h` will include `GL.h` (by default, at least, there are some preprocessor macros you can set to change that behavior, see [the GLFW build guide](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/build_guide.html#build_include) for details). In short: always inlcude your GL loader's header before all other stuff which might be GL-related:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

Also, you are lacking a call to `glewInit` to actually load those OpenGL function pointers.

And finally:

> ```
>     glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
>     glVertex2f(-0.5f,-0.5f);
>     glVertex2f( 0.0f, 0.5f);
>     glVertex2f( 0.5f,-0.5f);
>     glEnd();
> ```

That is not modern OpenGL - quite the contrary: this is the most leagcy and most outdated use of OpenGL you possibly could have. This immediate mode stuff was there since (GL 1.0 from 1992) and finally got deprecated with OpenGL 3.0 (in 2008) and *completely removed* from OpenGL 3.2 core profile and onwards (since 2009).

Comment: thanks for telling me about the include that did solve it and thanks for clarifying in the tutorial I was told this was just Opengl that well be using Modern OpenGL.THX

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are including glfw3 before glew. You can fix this by either changing the order in which you include them or put a #define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE before any of the includes