# Using GLAD for Raspberry Pi project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, raspberry-pi, opengl-es, glad

I am trying to figure out how to create a window for my project. I want to work with OpenGL ES and I found online guides on how to use X11 and EGL for creating the window, and this option works just fine.

But I am trying to follow OpenGL guides and all I can find use GLAD and GLFW to create a window, and it seems much easier to work with and understand, but whenever I try to use it I get a bunch of errors like *`'void glad_glClearColor(GLclampf, GLclampf, GLclampf, GLclampf)’ redeclared as different kind of entity`*.

I got 58 errors just like that one when I tried using the code from [here](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/1.2.hello_window_clear/hello_window_clear.cpp).

Is it not suited for Linux, or is there something else I am missing here?

Comment: https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad/issues/213 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62518500/compilng-error-with-modern-opengl-and-glew-libraray

Answer (score 0):

Raspbebrry is ARM based development card, I am not sure about GLFW support for raspberry pi but you can use SDL2 library with OpenGL bindings to create window and do some rendering